# Two of the same cameras giving different white balance values in Lightroom

Tags: canon, lightroom, white-balance

I have two cameras, both Canon 5D MkIII, both set to the same white balance.  The only difference is the lens.  One has a 24-70 f/2.8, the other has a 70-200 f/2.8 (both Canon brands).

When I import the pictures into Lightroom, each camera has a different white balance type.  While one shows `temp=5,100; tint=+22` the other shows `temp=-12; tint=-1`.

Not sure why Lightroom would do this, or what setting in the camera may be responsible, but is there a way to change the way temperature and tint are controlled in Lightroom?  I'm not sure what's up.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer shortly after I posted this.  I didn't reset one of the cameras from JPG (for a photo booth) to RAW (for this photo session).

The .CR2 file format supports full white balance control while the JPEG format has the white balance set and is just plus/minus from where it's set.

Comment: You can also accept this answer (the tick mark) to show that this question has been resolved. Stack Exchange explicitly encourages self-answered questions, so this isn't "gaming" the system or anything like that :-)

Comment: @PhilipKendall, Thank you Philip. I understand how SO works, but I'm not able to accept my own answer for 2 days.  So I have to wait until tomorrow.